# Non daemon threads in process terminated by task manager

Tags: python, multithreading, taskmanager

I am new to multi-threading so I apologize for the noob question in advance.

I am trying to understand what happens to a process with non daemon threads running when a user opens up the task manager and kills the process not gracefully?

Do these non daemon threads continue to run after the process is terminated? I am using python.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Threads always run in a process. If the process dies its threads die, too.

Comment: I was reading a post about non daemon threads that if the main thread exits and does not inform the daemon threads to end, then they will continue to run after the main thread ends. So it made me wonder about how daemon threads work with regards to process's being killed. Thanks for your post Michael Butscher! I suppose I was over thinking it. Any other information is happily welcomed!

Comment: On OS-level (at least I don't know an OS behaving otherwise) there is no concept of daemon vs. non-daemon threads. Therefore Python has to care about the daemon threads which are terminated when all non-daemons end (if nothing goes wrong). If the whole process is killed the OS kills all threads in it automatically.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you for taking the time to read this post and reply AND thanks for helping me understand this concept. Cheers!